# How can i find the changelist which made changes in a particular line on a particular file using Perforce command

Tags: perforce

I have a static analysis tool which gives me the file name and line number where it suppose an issue exists. Now using P4 command i want to pin point the user who has made that particular change. Means the developer who edited the file at that particular line number.
Is there a way to find out the changelist number which made change to a particular line in a file using p4 command so that i can integrate it in my script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are describing `p4 annotate`.
By default it prints the file with each line preceded by the revision number that the line was last changed. With option `-c` you can have the lines preceded by the corresponding changelist.
Call `p4 help annotate` for more details.